# How do I make this matching list code more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, list, matching

I have two lists. I want to get matching indices. I have come up with the following to illustrate as an example:

```
a = [1,2,6,5,3,4]
b = [1,3,4,2,5,6]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if b[j] != a[i]:
            next
        else:
            print(i, j)
```

Seems fairly straightforward, but a bit long. Can anyone help me make this code more efficient?

Output:

```
0 0
1 3
2 5
3 4
4 1
5 2
```

Comment: It would help to add the output

Comment: Desired output would be: `[[0,0], [1,3], [2,5],[3,4],[4,1],[5,2]]`. Currently, it just prints the matching indices.

Comment: Yeah I meant the current output. Anyway I added it for you.

Comment: You weren't specific enough :P haha thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> a = [1,2,6,5,3,4]
>>> b = [1,3,4,2,5,6]
>>>
>>> [[i,j] for i,k in enumerate(a) for j,v in enumerate(b) if k==v]
[[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,6,5,3,4]
b = [1,3,4,2,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]

b_dict = {}
for i, n in enumerate(b):
    if n not in b_dict:
        b_dict[n] = []
    b_dict[n].append(i)

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in b_dict:
        for index in b_dict[a[i]]:
            print(i, index)
```

O(a+b) solution, since "in" in a dict is O(1)

update verion allow match duplicate number in b

Comment: Hi, nice approach! You can replace the first loop with `b_dict = dict(enumerate(b))`

Comment: You could simplify the second loop by using `enumerate`, similar to @game0ver's answer and mine, i.e. `for i, m in enumerate(a): if m in b: print(i, b[m])`

Comment: I realized something else while I was applying this. You can only consume one instance of b. So you cannot match multiple elements in a to one b.

Answer (score 1):

Tips

1. If you have a loop that uses indices and their respective values, use `enumerate` instead of `range(len())` and indexing.
2. In this case you don't need to bother with the non-matching condition (`if b[j] != a[i]`).

```
>>> for i, v0 in enumerate(a):
...     for j, v1 in enumerate(b):
...         if v0 == v1:
...             print(i, j)
... 
0 0
1 3
2 5
3 4
4 1
5 2
```

As a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, v0 in enumerate(a) for j, v1 in enumerate(b) if v0 == v1]
[(0, 0), (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 2)]
```

(I outputted tuples cause they seem to make more sense in this context.)